# How to check information like when, whom,where the greenplum function created in database?

Tags: function, greenplum

Is there way to get information like when,whom,where the Greenplum database functions created. It is highly appreciated if you could provide me sample queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the `gp_toolkit` schema installed : Try this as a starting point:

```
SELECT 
    logtime, loguser, logmessage 
FROM 
    gp_toolkit.gp_log_database 
WHERE 
    logmessage ILIKE '%CREATE FUNCTION%' ;
```